# Is Set Cover problem with subsets of size ≤2 solvable in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, np, matching, set-cover

I came across the below question where the polynomial time solution to the "Set Cover Problem" is discussed when the subsets are of size EXACTLY 2.
[Set cover problem with sets of size 2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/77575/set-cover-problem-with-sets-of-size-2)

The solution described involves constructing an Edge Cover for a slightly different graph (Create a graph of keys and each edge links the keys of a subset).

Can we still solve it in polynomial time if there are some subsets of size 1 along with the subsets of size 2? I am unable to come up with a formulation for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Given an instance $\Pi$ of set cover with non-empty subsets of size at most 2, consider two instances of set cover with subsets of size exactly 2:

- $\Pi'$ contains all subsets in $\Pi$ of size exactly 2.
- $\Pi''$ contains all subsets in $\Pi$ of size exactly 2, and in addition, for each singleton $\{x\} \in \Pi$, the subset $\{x,z^*\}$, where $z^*$ is a new element (the same element is used for all singletons).

If an optimal solution for $\Pi$ doesn't use any singletons, then it will also be an optimal solution for $\Pi'$. Otherwise, it will be an optimal solution for $\Pi''$.

---

**Solution 2**

Let $\Pi$ be an instance of set cover with non-empty subsets of size at most 2. Say that a singleton $\{x\} \in \Pi$ is *covered* if $\Pi$ contains some set $\{x,y\}$. Any solution for $\Pi$ which uses $\{x\}$ could instead use $\{x,y\}$, so we can remove all covered singletons from $\Pi$. All singletons that remain in $\Pi$ must participate in any set cover, so we can set them aside, obtaining an instance $\Pi'$ in which all subsets have size exactly 2. Given an optimal solution for $\Pi'$, we obtain an optimal solution for $\Pi$ by adding all uncovered singletons that we had set aside.

Comment: This is concise and more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation.
The reasoning in Solution 2 is incredibly beautiful.